I cannot update the values ​of the rows in the GridView
I'm working with backgroundworker
I have a backgroundWorker 2 DoWork event, and in this event, I want to write 1 in the last column of the column for the operations that enter the try block, and 0 if they enter the catch block, but I could not achieve this.
`private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        geciciListe = new List<Sunucular>(sunucuListesi);
        List<String> basarilibaglantiList = new List<String>();
        List<String> basarisizbaglantiList = new List<String>();


        foreach (var sunucum in geciciListe)
        {
            Sayac = Sayac + 1;
             rowIndex = Sayac - 1;

            try
            {
                connectionStringTest = "Server=" + sunucum.ServerAdi + "; Database=" + sunucum.DatabaseAdi + "; User Id=biltekbilisim; Password = Bilisim20037816";
                sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringTest);
                sqlconnection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sorgu, sqlconnection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                anlikksunucuadi = sunucum.ServerAdi;
                sunucuKaydetme();
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    gridView.SetRowCellValue(rowIndex, "Durum", "1");
                });


                basarilibaglanti += 1;
                basarilibaglantiList.Add(sunucum.ServerAdi);
                sqlconnection.Close();
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(Sayac, sunucum.ServerAdi);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                basarisizbaglanti += 1;
                basarisizbaglantiList.Add(sunucum.ServerAdi);
                Log.SendError(ex.ToString());
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                    gridView.SetRowCellValue(rowIndex, "Durum", "0");
                });

            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconnection.Close();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Başarılı bağlantı " + basarilibaglanti + " Başarısız bağlantı " + basarisizbaglanti);
        basarilibaglanti = 0;
        basarisizbaglanti = 0;
        listele();
    }`

I couldn't get it to work anyway. I couldn't do it with SetRowCellValue either.
